# Question about finite/infinite intersection

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

1. $A= \bigcap_{i \in \mathbb{N}} (-1+\frac{1}{i}, \frac{1}{i})$
2. $B= \bigcap_{i=1}^{n} (-1+\frac{1}{i}, \frac{1}{i})$ with $n<\infty$

In case of $A,$ I think the intersection should be empty.

but I am unsure about $B$

the first few intervals would look like this

$i=1: (0,1)$

$i=2: (-1/2,1/2)$

$i=3: (-2/3, 1/3)$

$\vdots$

$i=n: (\frac{1-n}{n}, \frac{1}{n})$ $n<\infty$

so the value on the left would get smaller and 0 would be included in all intervals, but how about the right side?, the last value $\frac{1}{n}$ would be the smallest of all, could I just say the finite intersection would be $B=(0,\frac{1}{n})$?

Comment: You might want to look at the indices of your first set.

Comment: @QuantumSpace: Zero is not included in our definition of $\mathbb{N}$ if that is what you meant?

Comment: @galaxy-- I think Quantum mean that maybe is $i$ instead of $n$?

Comment: I agree with your aim for $B$, galaxy--!

Comment: @Quiet_waters: thank you :)  I edited it now.

Comment: @galaxy--, welcome, however I do not agree with your aim for $A$. Note that $0$ is not on intervals, so I think the intersection is empty

Comment: @Quiet_waters: oh you are right, we are open on both sides, so A would be empty and does my solution to the second look correct?

Comment: You might want to notice that everything in the infinite intersect must be in the finit intersection as well and so $\cap^{\infty} \subset \cap_{m=1}^n$ and as $\{0\}\not \subset (0, \frac 1n)$ your two answers can't both be correct..... You might also want to notice that $-1 +\frac 11 = 0$ and $0\not \in (-1+\frac 11, \frac 11)= (0, 1)$ ....(endpoints are *not* in the intervals)... if you think about that, I am *certain* you will be able to figure this out on your own.  Otherwise your reasoning is perfectly correct.

Comment: @galaxy-- yes, good studies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $0 \not \in (-1 +\frac 11, \frac 11)= (0,1)$ we can't have $0$ in any of either the finite or infinite intersections.

If $r > 0$ then there is an $m > \frac 1r$ and $\frac 1m < r$ so $r \not \in (-1 +\frac 1m, \frac 1m)$ and so $r$ will not be in any intersection that includes an index $m > \frac 1r$.  As the infinite intersection includes that index, no $r>0$ will be in the infinite intersect.

As for whether $r$ is in the finite intersection, we'll get to that in a moment.

If $r < 0$.... then $r < 0 = -1 + \frac 11$ so $r \not \in (-1 +\frac 11, \frac 11)=(0,1)$ so $r$ is not in any of the intersections finite or infinite.

So there is no values that are in the infinite intersection.  So $\bigcap_{m\in \mathbb N}(-1+\frac 1m, \frac 1m) =\emptyset$.

And if $\bigcap_{m=1}^n (-1+\frac 1m, \frac 1m) \subset (0,\infty)$.

Okay.... back that that observation that if $m > \frac 1r$ then $r\not\in (-1+\frac 1m, \frac 1m)$.

Well..... let's step back.   If $0< r < \frac 1n$ then $r < \frac 1n < \frac 1{n-1} <....$ and $r < \frac 1m$ for all $\frac 1m$ (and, of course, $r > 0 \ge -1+\frac 1m$) so $r\in (-1+\frac 1m, \frac 1m)$ for all $m \le n$ so $r$ is in the finite intersection.

But if $r\ge \frac 1n$ then $r\not \in (-1+\frac 1n, \frac 1n)$ and $r$ is *not* in the finite intersection.

So $\bigcap_{m=1}^n (-1+\frac 1m, \frac 1m) = (0, \frac 1n)$.

=======

Here's a slicker way to view it.

Consider $r \in \cap_{\alpha \in A} (a_\alpha, b_\alpha)$.  Then $r $ is in every interval $(a_\alpha, b_\alpha)$ so $r > \max a_\alpha$ if a maximum element exists and $r \ge \sup \max a_\alpha$ if a maximum element doesn't exist.

And the same reasoning to conclude $r < \min b_\alpha$ if a minimum element exist or $r \le \inf b_\alpha$ if it doesn't.

ANd thus the intersection can be determined by considering whatever interval can be made from $\max,\sup a_\alpha, \min,\inf b_\alpha$.

(If $\max,\min$ exist that side of the interval will be open and not include the $\max, \min$; otherwise it will be closed and will include the $\sup, \inf$; If $\max,\sup  a_\alpha > \min,\inf b_\alpha$ then the intersection will be empty; and if $\sup a_\alpha = \inf b_\alpha$ it will be the single point.

So $\max_{m\in \mathbb N} (-1+\frac 1m)=\max_{m\le n}(-1+\frac 1m) = (-1+\frac 11)=0$.

And $\min_{m< n}\frac 1m = \frac 1n$. So $\cap_{m=1}^n (-1+\frac 1m,\frac 1m) =(0,\frac 1n)$.

And $\min_{m\in \mathbb N}\frac 1m$ does not exist and $\inf_{m\in \mathbb N}\frac 1m = 0$.

So if $r\in \bigcap_{m\in \mathbb N}(-1+\frac 1m,\frac 1m)$ then $r > \max -1 + \frac 1m = 0$ and $r \le \inf \frac 1m = 0$.  So $0 < r \le 0$ which is impossible.  So  $ \bigcap_{m\in \mathbb N}(-1+\frac 1m,\frac 1m)= \emptyset$.

Comment: Why does someone with a reputation over 100000 write $\cap_{m=1}^n(-1+\frac 1 m,\frac 1 m)$ instead of $\bigcap_{m=1}^n(-1+\frac 1 m,\frac 1 m) \text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: @fleablood thank you so so much, for writing that in such a detailed manner.